# Как передать массив во Vue компонент из Blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, blade

Я пытаюсь передать массив во Vue компонент, но во Vue он отображается как undefined. Где я допускаю ошибку?

Передавал такими способами :

```
:quizInfo='@json($currentTestInfo)'

:quizInfo='{{ ( json_encode($currentTestInfo)) }}'
```

Comment: :quizInfo='{{  json_encode($currentTestInfo) }}' вроде верно, только без наружних скобок.